# VSTS - dotnet restore - PackageCache doesn't exist

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops

I'm trying to build a .net core webapi project on a vsts hosted agent.
I use the same yaml accross multiple projects and it works fine:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@1
    displayName: Restore
    inputs:
        command: restore
        projects: '$(ProjectName).Backend/*.csproj'
```

However, today, on a new project, the `dotnet restore` gave me the following error:

```
2018-06-23T09:23:21.5607282Z ##[section]Starting: Restore
2018-06-23T09:23:21.5610673Z ==============================================================================
2018-06-23T09:23:21.5610898Z Task         : .NET Core
2018-06-23T09:23:21.5611078Z Description  : Build, test and publish using dotnet core command-line.
2018-06-23T09:23:21.5611445Z Version      : 1.0.2
2018-06-23T09:23:21.5612188Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-06-23T09:23:21.5612456Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832194)
2018-06-23T09:23:21.5613271Z ==============================================================================
2018-06-23T09:23:22.0071300Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" restore D:\a\1\s\MyApp.Backend\MyApp.Backend.csproj
2018-06-23T09:23:24.2324967Z   Restoring packages for D:\a\1\s\MyApp.Backend\MyApp.Backend.csproj...
2018-06-23T09:23:24.5505741Z   Restoring packages for D:\a\1\s\MyApp.Dtos\MyApp.Dtos.csproj...
2018-06-23T09:23:24.5506660Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : The local source 'D:\a\1\s\PackageCache' doesn't exist. [D:\a\1\s\MyApp.Backend\MyApp.Backend.csproj]
2018-06-23T09:23:25.8083235Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
2018-06-23T09:23:25.8094330Z ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : D:\a\1\s\MyApp.Backend\MyApp.Backend.csproj
2018-06-23T09:23:25.8105780Z ##[section]Finishing: Restore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't understand why I got the error on that project and not on others, it disappeared once I upgraded the vsts task to `DotNetCoreCLI@2`.